# Is there an automated way to backup/clone a database and transform confidential data?

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-atlas

I have a production DB on MongoDB Atlas that I copy over to my staging DB so I can test features out with complete data sets.

However, I want to make sure to update all the passwords and confidential fields to random or hardcoded values like "FOOBAR" so that no user data is compromised.

Is there a common way of doing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to write a script/program that does what you want to the data.

From there, you have a few options.

You can use `mongoexport` and pipe your backup into the script directly (the script would need to be a shell script)

You can use mongodump and mongorestore to restore the database to another location and then run the script - the script could be in javascript, run with:

```
mongodb [options] script.js
```

There's no way in Atlas to do this directly.

I would recommend using field-level encryption so you don't ever have to worry about this - https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/security-client-side-encryption/ - but that would take time to convert your important fields, so you can use the above as a stopgap.